# Show $L^M=L^{\langle M\rangle}$

Tags: galois-theory

Let $L/K$ be a field extension and $M\subset\text{Aut}_K(L)$ a subset. Then for $\langle M\rangle\subset\text{Aut}_K(L)$ $$L^M=L^{\langle M\rangle}.$$
I need hints, I don't know how to start here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $L^{\langle M\rangle} \subseteq L^{M}$; if $l \in L$ is fixed by all the automorphisms in $\langle M\rangle$, then it is fixed by all the automorphisms in $M \subseteq \langle M\rangle$.

For the other inclusion, let $l \in L^M$. For any $\phi \in \langle M\rangle$, $\phi = \theta_1\circ\theta_2\circ\dots\circ\theta_n$ where $\theta_i \in M$ or $\theta_i^{-1} \in M$.